# Making Composer and Git work together

Tags: git, yii2, composer-php

I got a problem and am not sure how to solve it. I am working on a project that is version controlled by git. The actual framework is installed via composer (Yii2). Now I switched machines and wanna re-install everything as well as update it to the current state of the git repository. But either way I do it, using composer first to install the framework or cloning the git repository first, the subsequent step always complains that the directory is not empty. The obvious problem when cloning is that the vendor directory gets ignored as intended, where the framework resides. Git also complains if I install the framework first via composer and then pull the repository (error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:...).

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I "solved" with a workaround: I cloned my git repository in one folder and installed the framework via composer in another folder. Then, I copied all files from the framework folder into the git repository folder (and of course skipped all replacements of files). Now everything works fine, but I think this should be easier somehow, maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first clone your project using git, then install libraries using composer and then add directories with those libraries into .gitignore. Using this way on my projects and works fine. Even if you have composer.json in git repo, you need only to run composer update after git clone and it's done.

Comment: Yeah, I see what I probably did wrong.. I should've used "composer update" instead of "composer create-project ..." - also see my comment in the post of SilverFire above.. Thanks for answering and clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I didn't get the problem correctly, but are you cloning `yiisoft/yii2` repository manually? Usually you don't take care about `vendor` dir and it's content, because it must be ignored in git. You must have `composer.json`, with `"yiisoft/yii2": "*"` requirement and that's all.

To understand this, create an empty dir, execute `composer init`, add a Yii2 requirement line and call `composer update` - it will create the `vendor` dir and hydrate it will all, that is needed for Yii2.

Take a look at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I install yii2 via composer, and I want the rest of my files to be cloned / pulled from my git repository. So I either
a) First "git clone" (which creates my project directory) and then "composer create-project ..." in said directory OR
b) "composer create project ...." which creates my project directory and then "git clone ..." in said directory
either way I get an error. But I see what I maybe did wrong.. I get the composer.json by git clone-ing first.. So I should've rather used "composer update" instead of composer "create-project ..."?